# Finding events in a MySQL table, manipulating and storing the data

Tags: php, mysql

This is question I have still not been able to resolve, so maybe I need to be clearer in what I need.

I have a datasource which I receive and upload to a MySQL database each month.  I cannot alter the data although it may not be in the most helpful format. It looks like this:

```
Ref    Action  Date/Time          User      Location
00123  Create  01:02:12_09:13:13  J Jones   Home  
00456  Create  01:02:12_09:13:13  J Jones   Home  
00123  Revise  03:02:12_15:20:01  A Smith   Home   
00789  Create  01:02:12_09:13:13  J Jones   Home  
00123  Delete  05:02:12_10:51:45  B Halls   Home
```

x 1000's

It tracks events that occur against a reference number, which is generated by the first event (the Create event).  These events occur at varying intervals and are done by various people in various locations.

Using the above example I need to be able to loop through the data for a particular month, pull out a reference number and its 'Create' event, then locate all the other events for that ref number.

I then need to be able to manipulate this information, for example calculate the time difference between Create and Revise, and then Revise and Delete, and who did them, where.

I need to be able to this for all the ref numbers created in the month or a date range.

So I am hoping I can create a query that can do this - find a ref number, find the other events, string them together in some way - so that in the end I have new data -

Ref Number, Time of Create, Create By Who, Time of Revise/By Who, Time of Delete etc

It would be useful if this new data could be stored in a new table, I would think(?)

Can this be done as a query or perhaps combination of query and PHP (arrays?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the first stage is to transform this data in a MySQL table, and
you will have something like

```
ref integer,
action  enum('create','revise','delete'),  -- ordered by life cycle: create first, delete last
ts  timestamp,
user    varchar(32),    -- or maybe user_id
loc varchar(32),    -- again maybe location_id, or ENUM
```

So to pull out an event given its reference

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ref = 123 ORDER BY action;
```

For date ranges you can use

```
WHERE ts BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'
```

To get time differences,

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(b.ts, a.ts) AS delta, b.*
    FROM mytable AS a
    JOIN mytable AS b ON (a.action = 'CREATE' AND a.ref = b.ref)
    WHERE a.ref = 123;
```

Finally to denormalize the table:

```
SELECT _create.*,
    TIMEDIFF(_revise.ts - _create.ts) AS revise_delta,
    TIMEDIFF(_delete.ts - _delete.ts) AS delete_delta,
FROM mytable AS _create
    LEFT JOIN mytable AS _revise ON (_create.ref = _revise.ref
               AND _create.action = 'CREATE' AND AND _revise.action = 'REVISE' AND ***)
    LEFT JOIN mytable AS _delete ON (_create.ref = _delete.ref
               AND _create.action = 'CREATE' AND AND _delete.action = 'DELETE' AND ***)
;
```

Here *** is some way of identifying the unique relation between a CREATE event and the corresponding DELETE event.

If refs are unique, then `AND ***` is not needed (*** equals to True).

For example if the refs are recycled every month, and it never happens that an event may span two months, you can impose that the year and month of _create should be the same as those of _revise; that and the equality of .ref establish a biunivocal match.

Otherwise it gets *much* more complicated, and I'd try creating a `VIEW` that for each CREATE event selects the `COALESCE` of `NOW()` and the datetime of the earliest `CREATE` event with that same ref but ts greater or equal to the current. This way you identify a "window" in which events with that ref *should* be attributed to that specific CREATE. But this is based on the hypothesis that it never happens that

```
00123 CREATE 01-NOV-2012 Jack
00123 CREATE 04-NOV-2012 Jill
00123 DELETE 05-NOV-2012 Joe  <-- which event is this one?
```

Comment: Thanks Iserni. I shouldve mentioned, the data is already in a MySQL table much like yours.  I just tried your time differences query - it returns multiple entries for each ref number, but besides that does work out the time diffs - thanks.  However, it returns a SELECT * type result.  I there a way I can manipulate what is returned to a  format like - REF, Create_time, Revise_time, Delete_time - for inserting into a new table laid out this way?

Comment: When a create event occurs a unique ref is created. This ref is stored against each future event, revise, delete etc.  I have run the query again and the first 'delta' result is 00:00:00, then on the next line the Create event is repeated with a delta of -101:01:13, then repeated again with delta of -838:59:59.  Then the revise event is shown with a delta of 101:01:13 - which looks correct in hours

Comment: Sorry. I had forgotten to add a constraint to one of the tables, I only saw that when I expanded the query to denormalize the data. The first "master" table should have selected *only* the CREATE rows: my bad.

Comment: Thanks Iserni. The revised time difference query works great. The new 'denormalize the table' query (which I must admit I dont understand fully) returns SQL Error (1582): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'TIMEDIFF'.  BTW refs are NEVER recycled - if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get field values for a particular action:

```
$db_connection = mysqli_connect();//Have DB variables here
$ref = ;//Ref number here e.g 123
$action = '';//action to check for here e.g create

$query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE ref=".$ref." AND action=".$action."";
$q = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_asocc($q)){

//The variables are in the $row array with each on an index based on a column name

}
```

Comment: Thanks William. So in your approach, I pull the data into PHP and do the calcs there? I need this to be done for all the ref numbers created in a month, so I guess I could create a another query to do this and feed this into $ref...

Comment: Yeah...you pull the data into PHP then do the calcs there. Although if the calcs can be done using MySQL, use that. MySQL is coded in C++ therefore it's calculations are much faster than PHP's which is an interprated language.

Comment: Isernis queries (above) will allow me to do it in MySQL it seems - but thanks for the input